# Unknown provider: Provider in Angularjs in my case

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I tried to use service but failed. My code as below

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'topicContent', function($scope, $http, topicContent){

  topicContent.request();

}]);

app.service('topicContent', ['', function(){
    return {
        request : function(){
            console.log('test');
        }
    }
}]);
```

I guess something is wrong with my dependency injection here..

Comment: Try changing `['', function(){` to `[function(){`

Comment: Also, services are not returned as objects. The code for your 'topicContent' is actually a factory. This will result in `app.factory('topicContent', [function(){`